# flink on yarn application mode couldn't deploy yarn application cluster

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

flink on yarn application mode, publish job timeout while yarn cluster still has enough resources to be used.

```
Used Resources:<memory:22GB, vCores:22>
Total Resources:<memory:109.54GB, vCores:64>
```

the `yarn-site.xml` parameters for resource configuration are as follows

```
 <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.authorization.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
</property>
```

exception info is as follows

```
2023-07-12 19:14:59,212:ERROR Thread-4724 (Yarncluster.java: 84) - ClusterDeploymentException :
org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterDeploymentException: Couldn't deploy Yarn Application Cluster
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnclusterDescriptor.deployApplicationCluster(YarnClusterDescriptor-java:465) 
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_322] 
    at java.Lang.Thread.run Thread.java: 750) [?:1.8.0_322]
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleeps
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep (Native Method)~[?:1.8.0_322]
    at org.apache, flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.startAppMaster (YarnclusterDescriptor.java: 1223) ~
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal(YarnClusterDescriptor.java:593)~[flink-! 
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnclusterDescriptor.deployApplicationcluster (YarnClusterDescriptor.java: 458 
    ...4 more
```

i tried turn on `yarn.nodemanager.resource.detect-hardware-capabilities`  to true in `yarn-site.xml` which enable auto-detection of node capabilities such as memory and CPU, but it doesn't work.

is anyone knows the issue and thanks in advance for any replies.